# How to get the Candles information when we are on another Candle type on the chart?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

As we have different candle types to choose on the tradingview, I am wondering if I can enforce in pinescript to get the candle information.

([image])

I realized that we have the option for other candle types (eg `ticker.heikinashi`), but we dont have this option for `Candles` as far as I know?
Is there a way to do it? like can I get the `Candle` data while I am on heikinashi chart?

I also tried using the `ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid)`, but apparantly, the that is something different, because as you can see in my simple code, when I choose `ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid)` it is different from the case that I select `Candles`.

Appreciate if someone know a workaround about it.

```
indicator("My script", overlay = true,max_lines_count = 500,max_labels_count=500)

fHigh_1(float hi0,float hi1,float hi2,float hi3) =>
    pHigh = (hi1 > hi2) and (hi0 <= hi1)
fLow_1(float lo0,float lo1,float lo2,float lo3) =>
    pLow = (lo1 < lo2) and (lo0 >= lo1)
// =================== Group: Nodes ================
GNodes = 'Nodes'
ShowNodes = input.bool(true," Show Nodes", group = GNodes)
// =================== Group: Candle ================
GCandles = 'Candle'
CandleTypeForPeakSelection = input.string(defval = "Current", title = 'Candle Type', group = GCandles, options = ["Standard","HeiKi","LineBreak", "Current"], inline = "D")
NumoFLines = input.int(2,"LineBreak NumLines", group = GCandles,options = [1,2,3,4], inline = "D")
// ============ Code ==================
chart_syminfo_tickerid = (CandleTypeForPeakSelection=="Standard")? ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid):(CandleTypeForPeakSelection=="HeiKi")?ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid):syminfo.tickerid
[lo_0,lo_1,lo_2,lo_3,lo_4,lo_5,lo_6,lo_7,lo_8] = request.security(chart_syminfo_tickerid, timeframe.period, [low,low[1],low[2],low[3],low[4],low[5],low[6],low[7],low[8]])
[hi_0,hi_1,hi_2,hi_3,hi_4,hi_5,hi_6,hi_7,hi_8] = request.security(chart_syminfo_tickerid, timeframe.period, [high,high[1],high[2],high[3],high[4],high[5],high[6],high[7],high[8]])
[ba_0,ba_1,ba_2,ba_3,ba_4,ba_5,ba_6,ba_7,ba_8] = request.security(chart_syminfo_tickerid, timeframe.period, [bar_index,bar_index[1],bar_index[2],bar_index[3],bar_index[4],bar_index[5],bar_index[6],bar_index[7],bar_index[8]])
peakHigh = fHigh_1(hi_0,hi_1,hi_2,hi_3)
peakLow = fLow_1(lo_0,lo_1,lo_2,lo_3)
offset = 1
plotshape(ShowNodes?peakHigh:na,   style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.blue,  offset = -1*offset , size=size.auto)
plotshape(ShowNodes?peakLow:na,    style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.belowbar, color=color.red,   offset = -1*offset , size=size.auto)
```

I was expecting the restults of choosing `CandleTypeForPeakSelection` as `Current` or `Standard` be the same when I am on the `Candles` style. but they are not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check [This](https://www.tradingview.com/v/TA4mVPD8/)

Comment: And [This](https://tradingview.com/script/U1QGgSOw-Heikin-Ashi-Source-Function-HTF/)